# jQuery div click post hide not working properly in IE8

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer-8, show-hide

I have a list of `div` elements created with javascript on the page that have the format:

```
<div id="UniqueID" class="request">
    <div class="request_main"></div> //VISIBLE
    <div class="request_info"></div> //HIDDEN
</div>
```

On clicking a `div`, the jQuery click listener handles a click event on the `request_main` element and searches the parent `div` for the `request_info` div. It then shows the `request_info` div if it's not already visible.

```
$(".request_main").live('click', function() {       
    $(".nrl").removeClass('blue').addClass('grey');                 
    if ($(this).parent().find(".request_info").css('display') == 'none') {
        $(".request_info").hide();  
        $(this).parent().find(".request_info").stop(false,true).show("slide", {direction:"up"}, 300, function(){});
        $(this).find(".nrl").removeClass('grey').addClass('blue');
        $(".links").removeClass('white').addClass('grey');
        $(".links").css('background-color','white');
        $(this).find(".links").removeClass('grey').addClass('white');
        $(this).find(".links").css('background-color','#1B75BB');
    }           
});
```

In Firefox, Safari, Chrome and even IE9 this works fine. In IE8 however, the function works only on divs that haven't been clicked before e.g. Click on `UniqueID_1` -> `request_info` displays. Click on `UniqueID_2` -> `request_info` displays. Click on `UniqueID_1` a second time -> nothing happens.

```
alert($(this).parent().find(".request_info").css('display'));
```

This statement returns `none` and `block` on each click with the working browsers. In IE8 this returns `none` and `block` the first time, then `undefined` after that (when clicking on the same div). This happens even if I explicitly set the values for the div in the function to `none` and `block` after the show and hide calls.

Comment: Please put it http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the following code:

```
$(".request_main").live('click', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: great thanks, this seems to have sorted it, And helped with a load of other things! Chris